# Heroku adding sbt start plugin prevents sbt plugin from resolving

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework-2.0, sbt

When adding the sbt-start plugin to push to Heroku, via build.sbt with the following contents:

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.startscript" % "xsbt-start-script-plugin" % "0.5.3")
```

I get an unresolved dependency with play:

```
[warn]  module not found: play#sbt-plugin;2.0.4
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/david-grandes/.ivy2/local/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.0.4/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/play/sbt-plugin_2.9.2_0.12/2.0.4/sbt-plugin-2.0.4.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/play/sbt-plugin_2.9.2_0.12/2.0.4/sbt-plugin-2.0.4.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: play#sbt-plugin;2.0.4: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Which is weird considering that if we remove the sbt-start-plugin, we can actually find the play plugin with no problems.

**EDIT**

Maybe its related to this specific version of the plugin? https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script/issues/23

Answer (score 0):

It is odd that removing the `sbt-start-plugin` allows `play#sbt-plugin;2.0.4` to be found because I believe that `play#sbt-plugin;2.0.4` is [only available for Scala 2.9.1 and SBT 0.11.3](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/webapp/browserepo.html?7&pathId=ivy-releases%3aplay/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/2.0.4/jars/sbt-plugin.jar). Perhaps when you added `sbt-start-plugin` you also changed the Scala or SBT version?

Nonetheless, unlike deploying other Scala web frameworks to Heroku, the `sbt-start-plugin` should not be necessary to deploy a Play 2.0 application to Heroku because [Play 2.0 already includes the required `stage` task](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ProductionDist) so deployment to Heroku should work out of the box. If you take a fresh Play 2.0 app, you can deploy it to Heroku without any modifications.

Comment: Hi ryanbraid! Thanks for the help. Actually, I didnt change the scala nor sbt versions. Effectively its running against scala 2.9.1 and sbt 0.11.3. Is this wrong or weird? What should it be? Anyways, thanks for the tip of not needing it, as well as the typesafe repository, I think it will be very handy.

Comment: One thing I just noticed is that the sbt-start-plugin 0.5.3 is for Scala 2.9.2 and SBT 0.12, so I wonder if that's somehow overriding the coordinates Play is resolved. sbt-start-plugin 0.5.2, on the other hand, is for Scala 2.9.1 and SBT 0.11.3, which should match Play 2.0.4, so it's worth a try to change it to 0.5.2 and see if that works for you. Again, its not really need (and might cause other problems with the `stage` task), but interesting to see if it resolves this issue.